# how to Monthly Summary for planned task. to display curve graph

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my first question after searching a log from google to resolve following challenge.

I want to display curve graph where Planned Vs. Actual graph will display so that management can check how much a project is behind schedule.

My Planned Table structure is as following

Table 1: ProjectTasks

```
Project ID
Task ID
Expected Start Date
Expected Finished Date
Task Weightage
Percent Complete
TaskGroup
```

Table 2: ProjectDepartmentWeightage

```
Project ID
Department
Weightage
TaskGroup
```

My Desired result is:

```
[Month-1:10%],[Month-2,:20%],[Month-3:5%] .... ==100
```

I tried following query but does not worked.

```
select 'M-'+convert(nvarchar(10),
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))) AS ItemNo,
       (ProjectDeptWeightage.Weightage * sum(TaskWeightage)/100) as prog 
from       ProjectTasks
inner join ProjectDeptWeightage 
on         ProjectDeptWeightage.ProjectID = ProjectTasks.ProjectID 
and        ProjectDeptWeightage.ResourceID = ProjectTasks.TaskGroup
where      ProjectTasks.ProjectID = 2244 
group by   year(EFDate),month(EFDate),ProjectDeptWeightage.Weightage
```

Comment: Are you using ROW_NUMBER()  as a Month number?

Comment: yes to het srial no of month for month-1,month-2,month-3